# cmake in windows requires all include directories to be lowercase

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I am having this weird issue where the paths that I use for my `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` has to be all lowercase.

My project has a subdirectory under it at `GLTestBed/src` if I try to include it , ninja  (or even the built VS solution) throws an error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ninja : error : '../../GLTestBed/src/Mesh.cpp', needed by 'GLTestBed/CMakeFiles/GlTestBed.dir/src/Mesh.cpp.obj', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Mesh.cpp is the first file added in my `add_Library` directive, if I remove that it throws this error for the file that is at top, so I am pretty sure its not an error for just this particular file

However if I change the folder name from `GLTestBed` to `gltestbed` every thing builds correctly

CmakeLists.txt in main Folder (GLParticles)

```
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    project(GLParticles)

    set (glparticlesdir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GLTestBed")

    message ("-----" , ${glparticlesdir}) 

    add_subdirectory(${glparticlesdir})

    add_executable(GLParticles
            src/main.cpp 
            src/ParticleWorld.cpp
            src/ParticleWorld.h
            src/BurstParticleUpdater.cpp
            src/BurstParticleUpdater.h src/SineWaveUpdater.cpp src/SineWaveUpdater.h)

    include_directories(${glparticlesdir}/src)
    include_directories(${glparticlesdir}/ext/glm)

    target_link_libraries(GLParticles
            GlTestBed)

    # SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-framework OpenGL")
```

and the CmakeLists.txt in the GLTestBed folder

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(GlTestBed)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
    #find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

    message ('--------'  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

    add_Library(GlTestBed
            src/Globals.h
            src/Mesh.cpp
            src/Mesh.h
            src/ResourceManager.cpp
            src/ResourceManager.hpp
            src/Shader.cpp
            src/Shader.h
            src/stb_image.cpp
            src/stb_image.h
            src/Material.h
            src/Engine.cpp src/Engine.h
            src/Particle.cpp
            src/Particle.h
            src/Camera.h
            src/Camera.cpp
            src/ParticleManager.cpp
            src/ParticleManager.h
            src/ParticleUpdater.h)

    target_include_directories(GlTestBed PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
    target_include_directories(GlTestBed PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glm)

    target_link_libraries(GlTestBed 
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} 
        glew32.lib 
        sfml-graphics.lib
        sfml-window.lib
        sfml-system.lib)

    if(APPLE)
        target_include_directories(GlTestBed PUBLIC
                /usr/local/include)
        target_link_libraries(GlTestBed
                /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib
                /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/lib/libsfml-window.2.4.2.dylib
                /usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.4.2_1/lib/libsfml-system.2.4.2.dylib ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
    endif()
```

Comment: Can you please show us your `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: @someprogrammerdude I added the CmakeLists files

Comment: It smell like you have weird *filesystem* on which your project is located, or.. your filesystem actually has **both** `GLTestBed` and `gltestbed` directories, when one *shadows* another. Try to copy your project sources into another place (e.g. the one which is definitely on NTFS or so), and build it from here. Also make sure that a build directory is also on a "stable" filesystem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev why do you think so ?, I have no directory named `gltestbed` in that folder. Also I am pretty sure that's not the case as this was happening for my `sfml` includes also as it also had an uppercase directory (include\SFML\...). I moved the SFML include directory to my global VC include directory, which strangely made it work.  Also the filesystem is NTFS, ever only used by windows 10 OS

Comment: Well, I have more interesting guess: try to make **project name** *different* from the **target name**. (That is, rename `project(GlTestBed)` to e.g. `project(GlTestBed1)`.)

Comment: tried that, cleaned the build directory and generated again , still getting the same errors :/. hope you have some more guesses

Comment: Hm, It seems that combination of CMake+MSVS actually doesn't like non-lowercase files/directories. I have found [this bugreport](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/372) about non-lowercased build directory, but your case could be very related with it. Such a strange co-workers: NTFS is case **sensitive** filesystem, but Windows (as OS) is case **insensitive**. CMake generator for MSVS knows this property about Windows, and tries to interpret some paths as lowercase. But the implementation seems to be not ideal... Or something like this - I don't quite understand that.

Comment: The bug report could just be an issue of the vscode-cmake-tools and not cmake itself, but who knows. I was looking forward to using cmake on windows as I required cross compatibility with OSX but that seems difficult now :/. BTW when you say **CMake generator for MSVS knows this property about Windows, and tries to interpret some paths as lowercase. But the implementation seems to be not ideal** are you basing it on something or are you just guessing it based on the available facts ?